# Descartes rule of sign multivariable

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

If I have a polynomial say $$7(1+x+x^{2})(1+y+y^{2})-8x^2y^2=0$$ is there a way to determine how many possible positive, negative, $\underline {integer}$ solutions exist?

Comment: infinite. The solution set  is one or more curves in the x,y plane

Comment: what if I restricted to integers?

Comment: I dont need to know what the solutions are just how many possible positive or negative integer solutions could exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation
$$7(1+x+x^{2})(1+y+y^{2})=8x^2y^2$$
does not have any integer solutions.

This is because 
$$\text{LHS}=7\bigg(1+\underbrace{x(x+1)}_{\text{even}}\bigg)\bigg(1+\underbrace{y(y+1)}_{\text{even}}\bigg)=\text{odd}$$
while RHS is even.

Answer (score 1):

568 has set of factors $\{1,2,4,8,71,142,284,568\}$

It is not possibe for $1+y+y^2 < 0$

Therefore we don't have to look at the negatives of the factor pairs.

There are as many as 2 roots for $1+y+y^2 = c$ for each of the facors, and 3 roots for $1+x+x^2 + x^3 = d$ where $cd = 568.$  That gives six potetial $(x,y)$ pairs for each $(c,d)$ pair.

Or, $48$ potential $(x,y)$ pairs.

Comment: But if you're looking for integer $x,y$ then none of those $48$ "potential" pairs actually works out.

Comment: I'm just unsure how this answers the question about knowing how many possible positive roots there are...descartes law of signs narrows it down in one variable so what I am trying to get at is how we can extend it any way by looking at change if signs... perhaps if we changed the equation to include some minus signs would that limit how many "possible " positive roots there are

Comment: Descartes rule of signs is not much help.  You could say, you have $x^3 + x^2 + x+ (1-d) = 0$ with $d\ge 1$ Descartes rule of signs says that this problem has at most one possibe root for each value of $d.$  You could also note $x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = (x+1)(x^2+1) = d$  cannot have a negative root.  As Gerry Myerson points out, there are, in fact, no integer solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very deep. In fact, [tenth Hilbert's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) states:

> Is there an algorithm which determines, of an arbitrary diophantine equation, 
>   whether it has a solution in the natural numbers?

The answer is negative, see the linked article for details.

For a specific

> **Question:** For which $d, k \in \mathbb{N}$ is there an algorithm to determine
>   whether a polynomial diophantine equation 
>   $$
>   P(x_1, \dots, x_k)  = 0, \ \ \ P \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_k]
> $$
>   of total degree $d$ in $k$ variables has a solution in integers? --
>   And for which $d$, $k$ is there no such algorithm,
>   respectively, is it unknown whether such algorithm exists or not?

see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207482/algorithmic-un-solvability-of-diophantine-equations-of-given-degree-with-given) MathOverflow thread.